# find all positive integers k so that there's a 10-element set M of positive integers such that exactly k triangles can be formed from M

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, induction, contest-math

> Find all positive integers $k$ so that there's a $10$-element set $M$ of positive integers such that there are exactly $k$ (distinct) triangles with sides lengths from $M$.

The positive integers $x,y,z$ form the sides of a triangle iff $x < y+z, y < x+z, z < x+y.$ Note that if we assume WLOG that $x=\max\{x,y,z\},$ it suffices to check that $x < y+z.$

For any $10$-element set $M$ of positive integers, $x,y,y$ can be the side lengths of a triangle for any pair $x\le y$ in $M$. So $k\ge {11\choose 2}=60.$ Also, there are ${12\choose 3}$ ways to choose a triple $x\leq y\leq z$ of elements from M, so $k\leq {12\choose 3} = 220$ (note they're in bijection with the set of 3-element subsets of $\{1,2,\cdots, 12\}$). I think the condition holds for $60\leq k\leq 220,$ and as for an approach I think induction might help. One could probably replace $10$ with $n$ to generalize.

> Questions about the solution below.

1. When $f_n(a) = k,$ how can one prove the set M defined satisfies $\Delta(m) = k$? Clearly there are ${a+2\choose 3}$ triangles that can be formed from $A := \{2^n + 2^1,\cdots, 2^n + 2^a\}$ but I'm not sure how to count the number of triangles in $M\backslash A$. And obviously no triangles can have one element in $A$ and another in $M\backslash A$ because the largest element in $M\backslash A$ will exceed the sum of the other two.
2. When $f_n(a) < k, c=0,$ how can one prove the set M defined work? The proof might be similar to 1 but it might involve more casework.
3. Similarly, how can one prove the set M defined when $f_n(a) < k, c > 0$ work?
4. How did the answerer know to define $f_n$? Did something in the question give this function away?

Comment: For any $x \in M$, there must also be a triangle with side lengths $x$, $x$, and $x$, right?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Have you considered upvoting and accepting my answer? Please comment if my answer can be improved. (This comment will be deleted upon feedback.)

Answer (score 1):

"The condition holds for $60\leq k\leq 220$". That is correct.

---

Let $\triangle(M)$ be the number of distinct triangles with side lengths from $M$.

As expected by the asker, we can prove the following general proposition.

> Let $n$ and $k$ are positive integers. There is a $n$-element set $M$ of positive integers such that $\triangle(M)=k$ $\iff$ ${n+1\choose2}\leq k\leq{n+2\choose3}$.

Proof:

"$\implies$": This have been shown in the question.

"$\impliedby$": Let ${n+1\choose2}\leq k\leq{n+2\choose3}$.
Let $f_n(x)={x+2\choose3}+\frac{(n+x+1)(n-x)}2=\frac{x(x^2-1)+3n^2+3n}{6}$, a strictly increasing function of $x\ge0$.
Let $a$ be the largest integer $x$ such that $f_n(x)\le k$, i.e, $f_n(a)\le k\lt f_n(a+1)$.
Since $f_n(1)={n+1\choose2}$ and $f_n(n)={n+2\choose3}$, we know $1\le a\le n$.

- $f_n(a)=k$.
  let $M=\{2^n+2^1, 2^n+2^2, \cdots, 2^n+2^a\}\sqcup\{2^{2n+1}, 2^{2n+2}, \cdots, 2^{2n+n-a}\}$.

  1. Any three values from the first set form a triangle.
  2. If the biggest value comes from the second set, it must appear twice since it is at least twice as big as the biggest value smaller than it. Apart from this double appearance, any no-bigger value including itself can be the third value to form a triangle.

  Hence $\triangle(M)={n+2\choose3} + (a+1) + (a+2) + \cdot + n = f_n(a)$.
- $f_n(a)<k$.
  Let $b$ be the largest integer such that ${b+1\choose2}\le k-f_n(a)$, i.e., ${b+1\choose2}\le k-f_n(a)\lt{b+2\choose2}$.
  Since $k<f_n(a+1)$, we have $k-f_n(a)\lt f_n(a+1)-f_n(a)={a+1\choose2}$. So $1\le b\lt a$.
  Let $c = k- f_n(a)-{b+1\choose2}$. Then $0\le c\lt{b+2\choose2}-{b+1\choose2}=b.$

  - $c = 0$.
    Let $$\begin{aligned}
    M&=\{2^{3n}-2^{2n-1},2^{3n}-2^{2n-2},\cdots,2^{3n}-2^{2n-(a-b)}\}\\
    &\sqcup\{ {2^{3n}+2^{1},2^{3n}+2^{2},\cdots,2^{3n}+2^{b}}\}\\
    &\sqcup\{ 2^{3n+1}\}\\ 
    &\sqcup\{2^{4n+1},2^{4n+2},\cdots,2^{4n+n-1-a}\}
    \end{aligned}$$
    Besides the triangles that are two values from the second set together with $2^{3n+1}$, the triangles that come from $M$ are the same as before: any three values from the first $a$ values, or double appearance of one value from the last $n-a$ values plus any one value not bigger than it.
    Hence $\triangle(M)={b+1\choose2}+f_n(a)=k$.
  - $c > 0$.
    Let $$\begin{aligned}
    M&=\{2^{3n}-2^{2n-1},2^{3n}-2^{2n-2},\cdots,2^{3n}-2^{2n-(a-b-1)}\}\\
    &\sqcup \{2^{3n}-2^{b-c}\}\\
    &\sqcup\{ {2^{3n}+2^{1},2^{3n}+2^{2},\cdots,2^{3n}+2^{b}}\}\\
    &\sqcup\{ 2^{3n+1}\}\\ 
    &\sqcup\{2^{4n+1},2^{4n+2},\cdots,2^{4n+n-1-a}\}
    \end{aligned}$$
    The triangles that come from $M$ are the same as the case above, except the extra ones that are like $\{2^{3n}-2^{b-c}, x, 2^{3n+1}\}$,
    where $x\in \{2^{3n}+2^{b-c+1},2^{3n}+2^{b-c+2},\cdots,2^{3n}+2^{b}\}$.
    Hence $\triangle(M)={b+1\choose2}+f_n(a) + c = k$. $\quad\checkmark$

---

Here is another proof of the direction "$\impliedby$".

Fix arbitrary $n, k>0$ such that ${n+1\choose2}\leq k\leq{n+2\choose3}$.

Let us construct a sequence of $n$-element sets $M_1, M_2, \cdots$ iteratively, starting from $M_1=\{2^1, \cdots, 2^{n-2}, 2^{n-1}, {2^n}\}$, increasing each number from $2^i$ to $2^{n}+2^{i}$ one by one for $i$ from $n$ down to $1$.

- $\{2^1, \cdots, 2^{n-2}, 2^{n-1}, \color{red}{2^n}\}$
- $\{2^1, \cdots, 2^{n-2}, 2^{n-1}, \color{red}{1+ 2^n}\}$
- $\{2^1, \cdots, 2^{n-2}, 2^{n-1}, \color{red}{2+ 2^n}\}$
- $\vdots$
- $\{2^1, \cdots, 2^{n-2}, \color{red}{2^{n-1}}, \color{red}{2^{n}+2^{n}}\}$
- $\{2^1, \cdots, 2^{n-2}, \color{red}{1+ 2^{n-1}}, 2^{n}+2^{n}\}$
- $\{2^1, \cdots, 2^{n-2}, \color{red}{2+ 2^{n-1}}, 2^{n}+2^{n}\}$
- $\vdots$
- $\{2^1, \cdots, \color{red}{2^{n-2}}, \color{red}{2^{n}+2^{n-1}}, 2^{n}+2^{n}\}$
- $\{2^1, \cdots, \color{red}{1+2^{n-2}}, 2^{n}+2^{n-1}, 2^{n}+2^{n}\}$
- $\{2^1, \cdots, \color{red}{2+2^{n-2}}, 2^{n}+2^{n-1}, 2^{n}+2^{n}\}$
- $\vdots$
- $\{2^1, \cdots, \color{red}{2^{n}+2^{n-2}}, 2^{n}+2^{n-1}, 2^{n}+2^{n}\}$
- $\vdots$
- $\vdots$
- $\{\color{red}{2^{n}+2^{1}}, \cdots, 2^{n}+2^{n-2}, 2^{n}+2^{n-1}, 2^{n}+2^{n}\}$

Let $M_e$ be the last set constructed.

Verify that $\triangle(M_1)={n+1\choose2}$, $\triangle(M_e)={n+2\choose3}$, $\triangle(M_t)\le\triangle(M_{t+1})\le\triangle(M_t)+1$. Hence there exists some $1\le w\le e$ such that $\triangle(M_w)=k$.

Comment: I appreciate the effort invested in this answer. However, I have a few questions that'll help me understand your solution better. So could you answer some of my questions?

Comment: Sure, please join [my chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139713/chat-with-apass-jack)

Comment: Could you look at [this number theory problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592903/find-all-pairs-of-positive-integers-a-and-b-so-that-for-every-prime-p-coprim) and [this IMO variant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592976/does-there-exist-a-set-of-positive-integers-a-satisfying-a-condition-related-to) if you have time?